# What is an algorithm behind the alignment tool in Meshlab?

Tags: algorithm, meshlab

I would like to use Align tool in Meshlab in my research. I understand that Meshlab uses iterative closest point algorithm, but maybe someone knows which exactly implementation is behind there? Maybe there are some references that I can use to cite the work of developers?

Thank you for your help!
Best wishes,
Mariya

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of the ICP can be found in the [VCG Library](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/vcglib): [vcg/complex/algorithms/align_pair.h](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/vcglib/blob/master/vcg/complex/algorithms/align_pair.h).